# Center one element above another element which is responsive and scales depending on screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive image gallery; jquery plugin called Galleria. I am trying to position div element on top of image gallery and center it vertically and horizontally inside Galleria regardless of screen size.

This is how it looks simplified inside my view:

```
<div class="galleria">
   <%= image_tag "gallery/1.jpg" %>
   <%= image_tag "gallery/2.jpg" %>
   <%= image_tag "gallery/3.jpg" %>
</div>

<div id="input-box">
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function start(){
        Galleria.loadTheme('theme/path');
        Galleria.run('.galleria', {
            wait: true,
            responsive: true,
            height: 0.5
        });
    }
</script>
```

I know if I would like to the position `input-box` above other elements and center it vertically and horizontally I would do something like this:

```
#input-box{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0 ;
  bottom : 0 ;
  left : 0 ;
  margin : auto;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 26;
}
```

This way element is always centered regardless of screen size. The problem is it is impossible to adjust it like that to be centered above Galleria because Galleria is responsive and scales differently. I tried to put `<div id="input-box">` inside `<div class="galleria">` but then it doesn't show at all. How can I accomplish to center one element above another element which is responsive and scales depending on screen size?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle please?

Comment: do you know for sure heights and widths of images and are they suppose to stack on top of each others or on line ? display:flex is one option

Comment: @GCyrillus, height and width of displayed images is changing depending on screen size. This is how gallery looks like:http://galleria.io. Difference in my example is that it is responsive so bigger the screen, bigger the gallery. I think I definitely need to figure it out somehow how to insert my div inside that Galleria div. Or to do it somehow with javascript...

Comment: @EliteGamer, I need something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kIiqv. The problem is if I post another div inside `<div class="galleria">`, it wont show up. Galleria somehow blocks it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just give it another wrapper, something like:

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="galleria">
   <%= image_tag "gallery/1.jpg" %>
   <%= image_tag "gallery/2.jpg" %>
   <%= image_tag "gallery/3.jpg" %>
  </div>

  <div id="input-box">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This should allow `.galleria` to be manipulated by the jquery as normal, which should *drive the size* of the `.gallery-wrapper`. Then with `.gallery-wrapper` set to `position: relative;` and the `#input-box` set to `position: absolute`, you should be able to center it as you desire on that extra wrapping element, which itself is being sized by the `.galleria` code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need following code

```
<div class="galleria">

    <%= image_tag "gallery/1.jpg" %>
    <%= image_tag "gallery/2.jpg" %>
    <%= image_tag "gallery/3.jpg" %>


    <div id="input-box">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>

</div>
```

And following CSS

```
.galleria {position:relative;}
.input-box {width:100px; height:200px; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; margin-left:-50px (half of its width); margin-top:-100px (half of its height);}
```

Even if the parent is responsive, the child(i.e. input-box) will always be in center (vertically and horizontally).

Comment: Thanks but I've tried to put `<div id="input-box">` inside `<div class="galleria">` but then my `input-box` doesn't show at all. It seems that this plugin blocks everything except images inside `<div class="galleria">`. Only if I could somehow insert it with javascript after Galleria loads?

Comment: use higher z-index on input-box then

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use display:table and table-caption wrapping input into a p :

```
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/180/"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/180/"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/180/"/>
  <div id="input-box">
      <form>
        <p>See me on top <input /></p>
        <p><input type="submit"/></p>
      </form>
```

```
div {
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  width:80%;/* or whatever */
}
div img {width:30%;}
div #input-box {
  display:table-caption;
  caption-side:top;/* or just : display:table-header-group; */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DCfBA

this a basic example. you can fix div widths adding `table-layout:fixed;` , hide `overflow` and set any other `width` to image. the point was to bring the `input` on top :)

anoter version for the fun to see it working somehow alike galleria: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yHIeo , click image to see next one ... it loops back to first one.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It works with normal pictures but it seems that `display:table;` breaks Galleria plugin. I need something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kIiqv

Comment: you need to use higher selector than the css file of galleria or use !important rules if CSS is send via javascript . your example cannot work since absolute kills display and that you set bottom for caption-side ;)

Comment: yours forked : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BAJrk another possibility http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yHIeo